# How do I force my training data to match the output shape of my neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the transfer learning example on [keras.applications](https://keras.io/api/applications/) using VGG19. I am trying to train on the cifar10 dataset, so 10 classes. My model is (conceptually) simple as it's just VGG 19 minus the top three layers and then some extra layers that are trainable.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.applications import VGG19
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Input
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#%%
# Specify input and number of classes
input_tensor = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
num_classes=10
#Load the data (cifar100), if label mode is fine then 100 classes
(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test)=tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
#One_Hot_encode y data
y_test=to_categorical(y_test,num_classes=num_classes,dtype='int32')
y_train=to_categorical(y_train,num_classes=num_classes,dtype='int32')
#%%
# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,
                   input_tensor=input_tensor)

# Add a fully connected layer and then a logistic layer
x = base_model.output
# # let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu',name='Fully_Connected')(x)
# and a logistic layer -- let's say we have 200 classes
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax',name='Logistic')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile the model (should be done *after* setting layers to non-trainable)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])


# train the model on the new data for a few epochs
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10)

#%%
model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
```

Now when I try to train using X_train [dimensions of (50000, 32, 32, 3)] and y_test (dimensions of (50000,10),

I get an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected Logistic to have 4 
dimensions, but got array with shape (50000, 10)
```

So for some reason the model isn't realizing that its output shape should be a 1x10 vector with one-hot encoding for the 10 classes.

How can I make it so that the dimensions agree? I don't fully understand the dimensions of output that keras is expecting here. When I do model.summary() the Logistic layer yields that the output shape should be (None, 1, 1, 10), which when flattened should just give a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VGG19 without the top layers does not return a fully-connected layer and instead returns a 2D feature space (output of a Conv2D/max pooling2d I believe). You'll probably want to place a flatten after the VGG, that'd be the best practical choice, as it will make your output shape `(None,10)`.

Otherwise, you could do

```py
y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (50000,1,1,10))
```